# Angular 4 nested form update

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nested-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I've got the following 'triple level' nested form:
FormGroup->ArrayOfFormGroups->FormGroup

Top level (myForm):

```
this.fb.group({
            name: '',
            description: '',
            questions: this.fb.array([])
        });
```

Nested form array element for 'questions':

```
this.fb.group({
            priority: ['1'],
            params: this.fb.group({parameter: ['']})
        });
```

Nested form group element for 'params' is a key:value object of random length.

I'm using the following ngFor to go through elements:

```
<tr *ngFor="let questionConfigForm of myForm.controls.questions.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
...
    <div *ngFor="let param of objectKeys(questionConfigForm.controls.params.controls)" formGroupName="params">
        <input type="text" [formControlName]="param">
```

I've got the following behavior:
When I'm updating any of the fields on first two form levels I could instantly see changes in corresponding form controls values with {{myForm.value | json}}.
But if I input something in one of 'params' controls I couldn't see any changes in myForm values, but the form data for 'params' controls will be updated if I will make any changes in corresponding 'questions' form.

For me it looks like 'param' form control receives input data, but doesn't trigger some update event, and I don't know how to fix that, except writing my own function to react on (change) and patchValue in form..

So my question is how to make 'params' controls update myForm without that strange behavior?

UPD:

```
initQuestionConfig() {
    return this.fb.group({
        priority: ['1'],
        params: this.fb.group({parameter: ['']}),
    });
}

addQuestionConfig() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['questions'];
    const newQuestionCfg = this.initQuestionConfig();
    control.push(newQuestionCfg);
}
```

Comment: Can you post code for how you are adding questions group to Top level form's questions array ?

Comment: @MilanRaval added to UPD section

Comment: Here params is not a single control, are you trying to bind it with INPUT ?

Comment: I'm using: *ngFor="let param of objectKeys(questionConfigForm.controls.params.controls)" to bind them to input

Comment: try adding {{}} for formControlName i.e. [formControlName]="{{param}}"

Comment: same behavior((

Answer (score 1):

Finally the problem is solved.

The root of this issue was the way I've cleaned up already existing 'params'.

To remove all parameters from 'questions' I used the following code:

```
const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['questions'];
control.controls[index]['controls'].params = this.fb.group([]);
```

And the reason of those glitches was this new 'fb.group' instance.

Now I'm removing params one by one, keeping original formGroup instance and it works as expected:

```
const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['questions'];
        const paramNames = Object.keys(control.controls[index]['controls'].params.controls);
        for (let i = 0; i < paramNames.length; i++) {
            control.controls[index]['controls'].params.removeControl(paramNames[i]);
        }
```

@MilanRaval thanks for your time again :)

Comment: Yay, you got it fixed !

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Give formArrayName and formGroupName like below...

```
 <div formArrayName="testGroup">
            <div *ngFor="let test of testGroup.controls; let i=index">
                <div [formGroupName]="i">
                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<label>
                            <input type="checkbox" formControlName="controlName" />                                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it acts the same way, it seems to be some kind of a bug. I will make workaround with patchValue and (change). Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Good if you can provid plunkr for it